# I don't walk, jog, run but I hope to. How can I get into habit of running?

Tags: jogging

I am getting fat every month and I just still at home. I always say OK I will run tomorrow but I don't. I even register in a GYM but I just went twice and then didn't go till my account finished. I want to walk outdoors but there is nothing that encourage me to do it. What should I do?

Regards.

Answer (score 9):

Kudos for wanting to be more active!

Here are some tips:

1. Enlist a gym/work-out buddy! Knowing someone is counting on you and holding YOU accountable for showing up will help motivate you to get moving. You can always walk to a mid-point and grab lunch together. But you **must** recognize if your "buddy" is making excuses and making it easier for you to quit too. Then you have to cut them loose!!!
2. If you can't enlist a buddy, try to just get outside: walk to the park or grocery store. Can you run some errands by walking instead of driving? Window shop?
3. Since you are just starting to run, alternate running and walking. Use landmarks like, "I'm going to jog to that tree".
4. **Write down your accomplishments!** This is very important in self-motivation especially if you see yourself starting to slack off. By keeping a log, you can see how far you've come and also keeps tabs on yourself for taking too many days off.
5. Don't feel like you need to be running for a certain distance or time to feel accomplished. That's why a personal log is good because it's relative to YOU and your only competition is yourself.
6. **Check out local running shops.** They usually have meet-up's on certain days and have all sorts of levels.
7. Check out running [websites](http://www.coolrunning.com/engine/2/2_3/index.shtml) for training programs and [forums](http://community.active.com/thread/143495). **You are not alone!**

Good luck! You can do it! :)

Comment: +1 - very detailed, nicely formatted, and links to external resources.

Comment: Wanting to run is not enough. @Rhea makes an excellent point about making excuses. Don't give youself any. What exactly is stopping you from doing it? They're likely just mental barriers. Establish a system (be active on this) so that it will change your behavior and create a habit (so it eventually becomes more passive).

Answer (score 3):

Rhea's answer is pretty good. I just wanted to expand on #4: track your progress. Seriously, this is massively motivating. Going back through a workout journal and seeing the progress you've made is amazing. As always, there is an [xkcd comic for it](http://xkcd.com/189/). If you are running in particular, an app like [RunKeeper](http://runkeeper.com/) can do a lot of the tracking, exercise planning & coaching for you, including recording distance, pace, intervals, plotting the run on a map and more.

Having said that, running isn't the only way to get in shape. If you don't enjoy it or can't get into it, consider other physical activities instead. Regularly play sports. Learn martial arts. Learn to climb & boulder. Try swimming, biking, or rowing. Take up weight training or Crossfit. Find something that you **enjoy** and can do **consistently** and the fitness & health improvements will come along for the ride.

Comment: @Goma - For whatever reason you seem set on walking/jogging/running...but like Yevgeniy says, "If you don't enjoy it or can't get into it, consider other physical activities instead."

Answer (score 0):

Rhea's covered a lot in her answer but another option is to sign up for a race. This may seem a bit much when you're starting from scratch but it will certainly provide an incentive to put on your trainers and go out the front door and will have the added benefit of completing the challenge.
There are usually plenty of 5k events targeting casual runners and if you choose one in about 3 - 6 months time then this will give you plenty of time to get ready.